# Get class by full package name in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have an xml with the following node:

```
<states package="my.package.states" start="preloader">
<item name="preloader" class="Preloader"/>
<item name="intro" class="Intro"/>
<item name="menu" class="Menu"/>
<item name="level_picker" class="LevelPicker"/>
<item name="credits" class="Credits"/></states>
```

And now I need to get a class reference to the class with the package attributes on states node plus the class attribute for each item... This is what I tried (among other stuff):

```
var c:Class = getDefinitionByName('my.package.states.Preloader') as Class;
```

And no success... Is there a way to get the result I want?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to use getDefinitionByName, the Class needs to be imported.
2. What you are trying to do there, will not work. MXML is just a markup language, which is "converted" to AS3 by the compiler. What you are trying to do, is like getting into a car and once you have started the engine, you expect the car to change into a motor-cycle, a plane and a refrigerator. This might work in "Transformers", but not in a program.

What you COULD do: inside of our "item"-component, you could create instances of those classes/components and add them to "item".